# FirebaseCrash error TARGET_BUILD_DIR: Value missing

Tags: ios, firebase, jenkins, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to follow the steps listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) to upload dSYMs to Firebase.

I'm using Jenkins as a build server. This is my script:

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id
Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/Service_Account/file.json"
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym:113: error: TARGET_BUILD_DIR: Value missing
```

How do I specify the target build directory?

Comment: How are you building your project? The reason that fails is because that script is meant to be executed under a project Build Phase; these have Xcode environment variables like TARGET_BUILD_DIR already setup. If you are using xcodebuild, try adding that script to a run script build phase after linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Eric Shieh's comment, the reason why the script was not working in Jenkins' build script was that certain environment variables that Xcode supplies are missing when running through Jenkins.

So, I added a run script phase as the documentation suggests and then marked the "Run script only when installing" option.

This option will only run the script when archiving occurs.